# How to bypass 503 BS4 python

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, http-status-code-503

How can I bypass 503 with BS4

Selenium works for a long time, so I would not want to use it

[site to request](https://mangalib.me/)

changing user-agent did not help

there is no cycle in the code, this error arrives from the first request

```py
header = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did just

```
import requests
r = requests.get("https://mangalib.me/")
```

and got 503 too, in `r.text` I found that

```
  <noscript>
    <h1 data-translate="turn_on_js" style="color:#bd2426;">Please turn JavaScript on and reload the page.</h1>
  </noscript>
```

and later

```
<div id="no-cookie-warning" class="cookie-warning" data-translate="turn_on_cookies" style="display:none">
  <p data-translate="turn_on_cookies" style="color:#bd2426;">Please enable Cookies and reload the page.</p>
</div>
<p data-translate="process_is_automatic">This process is automatic. Your browser will redirect to your requested content shortly.</p>
<p data-translate="allow_5_secs" id="cf-spinner-allow-5-secs" >Please allow up to 5 seconds&hellip;</p>
```

So I suspect you need tool with JavaScript support if you want to access this page